# QlikView Inline Code Formating

Tags: mysql, sql, qlikview

Greetings from a complete Noob!

I am trying to get the hang of coding in the latest Qlik Sense application. The code resembles MYSQL to a degree and I am looking for tips on solving one particular problem.

This is the code:

```
T1:
LOAD * Inline [
F1, F2
a, 1
a, 2
b, 3
c, 4
];
T2:
LOAD DISTINCT * Inline [
F1, F2
a, 1
b, 3
b, 3
c, 4
];
```

which produces following preview:

```
1. F1    F2
2. a     1
3. a     2
4. b     3
5. c     4
```

What I am aiming for is:

```
1. F1    F2
2. a     1
3. a     2
4. b     3
5. c     4
6. a     1
7. c     4
8. b     3
```

I figured out that T1 and T2 are not different Tables according to the code, so I am looking for a way to make them such and then join them with the parameter of "DISTINCT"

OR

I am looking for a parameter that would apply the "DISTINCT" to only the T2 section of the code.

Any Suggestions or Help are very Welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over thinking it. All the data is there if you just load it without the DISTINCT. The DISTINCT is going to remove some of the data since it repeats from the first inline load.

So this:

```
T1:
LOAD * Inline [
F1, F2
a, 1
a, 2
b, 3
c, 4
];
T2:
LOAD * Inline [
F1, F2
a, 1
b, 3
b, 3
c, 4
];
```

Gives you this:
[image: F1 List Boxes]

Trick is that List Boxes only show each value once but if you add them up in a chart you get 21 which I expect is the answer you want (it's 10 if you keep the distinct because it has dumped the duplicate rows)

[image: F1 Chart]

If you want to be able to see the data line for line in the front end you will have to give it a unique identifier something like this:

```
T2:
LOAD * Inline [
G1, G2,G3
a, 1,1
a, 2,2
b, 3,3
c, 4,4
];
T2:
LOAD DISTINCT * Inline [
G1, G2,G3
a, 1,5
b, 3,6
b, 3,7
c, 4,8
];
```

Which will give you this: (looks the same)
[image: Same list boxes]

but now you can do this: (Same answer but you can split the rows out)
[image]

This is all because the Qlik engine is always trying to aggregate things that are the same. It would rather say "I have 3 of option a" than write out option a 3 times, so you have to force it not to if that is what you want to see. But the data will still be stored correctly however you want to see it.

A neater way to do the second version if you don't mind the unique identifier being arbitrary and prone to change as the data changes would be:

```
T2:
LOAD rowno() as G3, * Inline [
G1, G2
a, 1
a, 2
b, 3
c, 4
];
T2:
LOAD DISTINCT rowno() as G3, * Inline [
G1, G2
a, 1
b, 3
b, 3
c, 4
];
```

Comment: Thank You all for Your Answers!

I will try to implement the suggestions You've provided!